# Change display value of a div based on input value

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I want a button to appear when someone enters the correct value (a number) into a input type="number". I tried `var check=document.getElementById("buttonID").value == "1"` and then an `if` statement, but I must have done something very wrong.

This is how I want it to work.

1. input: 1 (press enter)
2. button appears

I currently have a button set to `display:none` and an input but that's it.

```
    #my input
    <div class="input-ruta">
        <input id="val" type="number">
    </div>
   #the button i want to appear when the input value is 1
   <div class="container">
        <a href="link" target="_blank"><button id="button2">
            <img class="image-class" src="image.png">
        </button></a>
    </div>
```

my code is messy but I hope you get what I'm trying to do

Comment: share your code , so we can see your issue. We cannot guess what you've really done ;)

Comment: var check=document.getElementById("buttonID").value; And then if(check===1) Do something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **check the value whenever the input changes**. That can be achieved by using [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) on the input element.

**Working example:**

```js
function checkInputValue(event){

  // Check if ENTER has been pressed
  if(event.key==="Enter"){
  
    // Check the value of the input
    if(document.getElementById("myInput").value==="1")
    {
      // Show button
      document.getElementById("hideButton").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      // Hide button
      document.getElementById("hideButton").style.display="none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" onkeyup="checkInputValue(event)">
<button id="hideButton" style="display:none;">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Finally, I've been trying to make this work for a while. Thank you.